# how to invoke logging constructor only after some condition checked?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using RollingFileAppender to write logs. The constructor for RollingFileAppender gets invoked as soon as my application starts. but I dont want it to happen at application restart, I need to check some flag in database and if it is set to some specif value then only start this logging, else dont start. So how to handle such scenario?

Comment: Give some details about your logging configuration, and where/how you are loading this configuration in your application. Also, does 'application restart' mean that the App Server is alive, but you're redeploying the ear/war?

Comment: I am using log4j.xml, which has appender defined it it like : '<appender name="loginLoggerAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">' My problem is this appender class calls DailyRollingFileAppender constructor whenever i start my application, but i dont want constructor to be invoked immediately instead it should do some check in Db and based on that it should invoke logger.